# What is the best way to display the latest 10 images from an album?

Tags: swift

This is what I am doing. A user chooses what album they want to use and the number of images they want to use from the album. For example 15 images. When a user navigates to a certain controller view it will display the first image and then they click next it will display the next image.... until they reach 15.

I am using the [PhotoHelper](https://github.com/AYastrebov/PhotosHelper) library for getting the images

```
var userAlbumArray: [PhotoAlbum] = []
var options = PhotosHelper.defaultImageFetchOptions
options.deliveryMode = .FastFormat

var fetchOptions = PhotosHelper.FetchOptions()
fetchOptions.count = 15

PhotosHelper.getImagesFromAlbum("Album Name", options: options, fetchOptions: fetchOptions, completion: { result in
    switch result {
    // When options.synchronous is set to true an array of all assets is fetched.
    case .Assets(let images):
        ()
    // when options.synchronous is set to false the system fetches one asset at a time calling this completion handler multiple times
    case .Asset(let image):
        let alb = PhotoAlbum(title: album.localizedTitle ?? "", thumbnail: image)
        userAlbumArray.append(alb)
    case .Error:
        ()
    }
})
```

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct PhotoAlbum {

    var title: String
    var thumbnail: UIImage?

    init(title: String, thumbnail: UIImage?) {
        self.title = title
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
    }
}
```

Since the images get loaded asynchronously my idea was to create a `PhotoAlbum` object for each image and add it to an array on App initial load.  Then save the array to `UserDefaults` once the user got the View Controller it will get the images from UserDefaults.

I tried saving it to UserDefault but I was not able to. It might be because of the UIImage.

Am I approaching this correctly or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I created this function for getting x number of images from an album:

```
    public static func getImages(albumName: String, number_of_images: Int = 1) -> [PHAsset]{
        var assets: [PHAsset] = []
        var assetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
        var photoAssets = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
        let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let firstObject = collection.firstObject{
            // found the album
            assetCollection = firstObject
        }

        let options = PHFetchOptions()
        options.fetchLimit = number_of_images
        photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: options) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>

        photoAssets.enumerateObjects{(object: AnyObject!,
            count: Int,
            stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

            if object is PHAsset{
                let asset = object as! PHAsset
                assets.append(asset)
            }
        }

        return assets
    }
```

Comment: This is not getting any "images" at all. You are fetching _assets_, which is merely information about / references to the photos in the photo library. That's great but it is not what you said you wanted.